# How I can remove formatting from text and convert it to URL?

Tags: formatting, url

I need to remove any type of formatting from a text to get an URL multi-formatting.
By keeping the following model, I have tried various solutions but without having the desired result.
Would anyone know how to find a solution?

```
\newcommand{\link}[1]{
    %
    % ?
    %
    \href{#1_WITHOUT_FORMATTING_AND_COMMANDS}{#1_WITH_FORMATTING}
}

\begin{document}
    \link{http://www.site.com/page.php?key1=\textcolor{red}{value1}\&\textit{key2=value2}/\textbf{page2}/page3}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should define a fixed set of formatting commands for showing a URL, in order to get better consistency across your document. Then you can apply David's suggestion with the set of formatting commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,color}


\newcommand{\link}[1]{%
    {%
    \def\textcolor##1##2{##2}%
    \def\textbf##1{##1}%
    \def\textit##1{##1}%
    \edef\&{\string&}%
    \xdef\tmp{\noexpand\href{#1}}}%
 \tmp{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
    \link{http://www.site.com/page.php?key1=\textcolor{red}{value1}\&\textit{key2=value2}/\textbf{page2}/page3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: replacing `\link` by `\url` in your code (hence `\link` definition can also be removed) gives very strange error with `\module` undefined in file supp-pdf.mkii

Comment: any idea about how ``undefined \module`` pops out from using `\url` (I did not trace it)

Comment: @jfbu the supp-pdf file gets read with `%` not being a comment

Comment: I'd prefer the first brace being `\begingroup` and finishing with `\edef\tmp{\endgroup\noexpand\href{#1}}\tmp{#1}`

Comment: Yes! It works great. It doesn't split only long url in tabular environment, like \url does. Thanks David.

Comment: @egreg it's only typeset no assignments so no real need to lift the local definitions out of the group is there?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The proposed code doesn't leave `\tmp` defined.

Comment: @egreg anyone who uses `\tmp` assuming a particular definition deserves what they get:-) in package code I'd use `\@tempa` or `\TX@tempa` rather than `\tmp` of course.

Comment: Can someone help me change the definition of `link` to automatically wrap the output?