# Hyphenation in LINK text

Tags: hyphenation, url

I use, in agreement with the [post of SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468033/how-i-can-remove-formatting-from-text-and-convert-it-to-url), the command `\link`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\link}[1]{%
    {%
        \def\textbf##1{##1}%
        \def\textit##1{##1}%
        \def\textcolor##1##2{##2}%
        \def\protect##1##2{##2}%
        \edef\_{\string_}%
        \edef\&{\string&}%
        \xdef\tmp{\noexpand\href{#1}}}%
    \ttfamily%
    \tmp{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|l|}
        \link{https://www.\textcolor{blue}{longlink}.com/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/} & Long link description\tabularnewline
        \link{www.\textcolor{blue}{longlinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglink}.net} & Long link description\tabularnewline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

and I get:

[image: Compilation output]

So… two questions:

- How can I change the text of `\link` to get the hyphenation on the slash character without the hyphen char?

and if there isn't any slash character

- How can I change the text of `\link` to get hyphenation anywhere but without the hyphen char?

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108003 can help you (i.e., the `breakurl` package with `anythingbreaks` option)?

Comment: No, with `\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}` i get: *Option clash for package hyperref*, and `\sloppy` doesn't work.

Comment: I've linked to a specific answer which does not mention the `breaklinks` option for hyperref, it uses a separate package for breaking links (called `breakurl`). Did you try that?

Comment: I'm sorry, `\usepackage{breakurl}` or `\usepackage[anythingbreaks]{breakurl}` don't work either.

Comment: I tried it myself now and it does not work indeed - and many other possible solutions also seem to fail for this specific case. I hope someone here comes along to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is the same, but using more powerful `expl3` methods.

With `\link{<link>}` you get the same as before, but with the possibility of breaking lines at slashes.

With `\link*{<link>}` you allow breaking at any letter. However this requires changing `\textcolor{blue}{<string>}` to `\blue{<string>}` otherwise also `blue` would be considered for breaking. Define similar commands for all colors you need and update the equivalences.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\blue}{m}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\link}{sm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \textbf \use:n
  \cs_set_eq:NN \textit \use:n
  \cs_set_eq:NN \blue \use:n
  \cs_set:Npx \_ { \c_underscore_str }
  \cs_set:Npx \& { \c_ampersand_str }
  \tl_gset:Nx \g_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \group_end:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { [A-Za-z] } { \0 \c{linebreak}[0] } \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { / } { /\linebreak[0] }
   }
  \group_begin:
  \ttfamily
  \exp_args:NVV \href \g_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright}X|l|}
\link{https://www.\blue{longlink}.com/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/} & Long link description\tabularnewline
\link*{www.\blue{longlinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglink}.net} & Long link description\tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to adopt the “break everywhere” strategy when there is no slash:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\blue}{m}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\link}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \textbf \use:n
  \cs_set_eq:NN \textit \use:n
  \cs_set_eq:NN \blue \use:n
  \cs_set:Npx \_ { \c_underscore_str }
  \cs_set:Npx \& { \c_ampersand_str }
  \tl_gset:Nx \g_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \group_end:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_match:nnTF { / } { #1 }
   {
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { / } { /\linebreak[0] }
   }
   {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { [A-Za-z] } { \0 \c{linebreak}[0] } \l_tmpa_tl
   }
  \group_begin:
  \ttfamily
  \exp_args:NVV \href \g_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright}X|l|}
\link{https://www.\blue{example}.com/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/longlink/} & Long link description\tabularnewline
\link{www.\blue{longlinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglinklonglink}.net} & Long link description\tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: Is it possible to get the second behavior in case of non-existence of the slash?

Comment: I get *Use of \@undeclaredcolor doesn't match its definition. \end{tabularx}* if i try to use another color like `\textcolor{red}`.

Comment: @BnG Yes, it's possible and I added it. As I said, you need to define `\red` for `\textcolor{red}` similarly as for `\blue` and to add the line `\cs_set:Npn \red \use:n` in the code.

Comment: Doh :-) !!! Is there no way to avoid the definition of all colors… or even better, to delete all the commands starting with `\`

Comment: @BnG Maybe, but the regular expression would be quite complicated. I think that defining *semantic* commands instead of using `\textcolor` is better; I used `\blue` and `\red`, but you can use whatever name that conveys the idea you want to express. This has also the advantage that you can redefine the colors uniformly in case of need, without chasing through the document.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. It works. Can you still show me what I should do for defining all \textcolor without \blue definition?

Comment: @BnG Sorry but I don't understand. Instead of `\blue` you can use whatever name is not already taken.

Comment: Ok. So I can't define, with *expl3*, something like `\cs_set_eq:NN \textcolor {color} \use: n` like the example shown in the question `\def\textcolor##1##2{##2}`.

Comment: @BnG Sorry, but that doesn't make sense. There are two sorts of problems: the `\cs_set_eq:NN` part is for removing the color declarations when building the URL; the `\blue` command is necessary for adding the break points in the *printed and formatted* URL.